# A Poker Game with XNA

Tags: xna, networking

A customer of mine asked me to develop a Poker Game for him where they play poker with his friends online.

I have been looking for a good reason to start programming with XNA.  Would you implement it with XNA if you were developing a game like this ?

Is there any ebook/online tutorials/video trainings which has some similar sample applications?

Comment: Which platforms are you planning to target? Windows only? X-Box??

Comment: windows only.. I would do this with WPF

Comment: Like this one http://wpfpoker.codeplex.com/ ?

Comment: that one seems inspiring but what about with XNA ?

Comment: See my answer below...

Comment: I have to do this now with Silverlight. Is there maybe a samle for silverlight as well ? I've been dealing with WCF Duplex and it is becoming a nightmare to me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing it XNA with will give lots of flexibility with fancy animations; otherwise if you want something simpler WPF is easier. I might be biased because I've just had 8 month straight programming with WPF/WinRT. Anyhow, MS actually has sample XNA card game http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/blackjack.

I also recommend this site for tutorials: http://rbwhitaker.wikidot.com/2d-tutorials

Answer (score 0):

As long as you don't want to use 3D i'd say skip XNA. Where WPF has an event driven model, XNA
uses a real time loop for updates in game logic. This makes several things more complicated, for example you don't have regular buttons to post the Blinds, Bet, Call or Fold. These would be images in XNA and you need to detect user clicks on the screen and find out if this click was on an image or not.

Doesn't wpf also have a lot of animation possibilities?